# F# compiler throws exception when invoked from spawned process

Tags: .net, process, f#

I spawn a new process and have it invoke the F# compiler like this:

```cs
var exeName = args[0];
var commandLine = args[1];
using (var process = new Process())
{
    process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(exeName, commandLine);
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    process.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;

    process.Start();
}
```

the arguments that I pass in are the path to fsc.exe and the arguments for the code that I want to build.
The result is exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: chop_extension
   at Internal.Utilities.Filename.chop_extension(String s)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Build.TcConfigBuilder.DecideNames(FSharpList`1 sourceFiles)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Driver.main1(String[] argv)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.ErrorLogger.ErrorLoggerExtensions.ReraiseIfWatsonable(Exception exn)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.ErrorLogger.ErrorLoggerExtensions.ErrorLogger.ErrorRecovery(ErrorLogger x, Exception exn, range m)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.ErrorLogger.errorRecovery(Exception exn, range m)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Driver.main1(String[] argv)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Driver.main(String[] argv)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CommandLineMain.main(String[] argv)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.ErrorLogger.ErrorLoggerExtensions.ReraiseIfWatsonable(Exception exn)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.ErrorLogger.ErrorLoggerExtensions.ErrorLogger.ErrorRecovery(ErrorLogger x, Exception exn, range m)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.ErrorLogger.errorRecovery(Exception exn, range m)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CommandLineMain.main(String[] argv)
```

However when I run the same command and arguments from the command prompt it compiles with no error

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: What are the arguments you have used? It could be the case that input strings are malformed.

Comment: You're calling the fsc exe from C# code?  That's what that first code fragment looks like and I just want to confirm my assumption.  I agree with Pad--show us the value of exeName and commandLine.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to give a specific answer without knowing what parameters are you passing to the compiler - the error probably comes from some ill-formed command line parameter.

However, if you want to invoke the F# compiler from C#, you don't need to do that explicitly using the `Process` class. You can use the F# CodeDom provider that is available in [F# PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/) - it takes care of formatting the parameters (and also locating the F# compiler, which can be quite subtle).

Here is a brief example that shows how you'd call it from F# (doing that from C# would be similar):

```
#r "FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.dll"

open System.CodeDom.Compiler
open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom

let provider = new FSharpCodeProvider()
let parameters = CompilerParameters()
provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(parameters, [| "C:...file.fsx" |])
```

Comment: Didn't realize you could do that directly from code.  Good to know.